# Custom Windows UWP JumpList for SecondaryTile

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, jump-list, secondary-live-tile

How can I use the UWP [JumpList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist?view=winrt-22621) API to customize the jump list for a taskbar icon created using the [SecondaryTile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile?view=winrt-22621) API?

```cs
var jumpList = await Windows.UI.StartScreen.JumpList.LoadCurrentAsync();
jumpList.Items.Clear();
jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("", "Foo"));
await jumpList.SaveAsync();
```

I have found that it's possible to get the HWND for a secondary tile using:

```cs
var window = // Reference to the app's main window.
var secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(...);

var hwnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(secondaryTile, hwnd);
```

However, I also don't see a way to set the jump list from the HWND.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve? SecondaryTile is in the Pinned list of the start menu in win11, which is different from jumplist.

Comment: I would like to add a jump list to a secondary tile icon that has been pinned to the taskbar in Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to add jumplist to SecondaryTile. We can refer to win11's built-in application Microsoft Store, there is also no jumplist in its SecondaryTile.

Comment: It seems its possible to get a hwnd for a secondary tile using `var hwnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window); InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(secondaryTile, hwnd);`. Is there a way to set the jump list using a hwnd?

Comment: For win11, the effect of secondaryTile is to add them to the pinned list of the start menu. I also tried to use the win32 method, but it seems that it cannot be achieved.

Comment: My above code to get the window handle doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to get the window handle for the secondary tile? Then there are a myriad of ways to use that to set the jump list.

Comment: I think adding jump list from HWND is not a feasible method. Even if you get the handle, you still can't do anything. At present, Win32 can only add Jumplist through [Windows Shell api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids).